# How rare is it for a team to face the minimum number of batters without a perfect game?

Tags: baseball, trivia, history

In the Cubs' victory over the Dodgers in game 6 of the 2016 NLCS the Dodgers sent only 27 batters to the plate (the minimum possible) yet were not the victims of a perfect game.

How often has this occurred throughout history, where a team sends only 27 batters to the plate but is not the victim of a perfect game or no-hitter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How rare is it for a team to face the minimum number of batters without a perfect game?

If we are just considering games in which a team faced "the minimum number of batters (27)," then not very rare at all.

If we are considering all games, then I'm sure it's rare to some extent.

> How often has this occurred throughout history, where a team sends only 27 batters to the plate but is not the victim of a perfect game or no-hitter?

Multiple times.

This [baseball reference search](http://www.baseball-reference.com/play-index/game_finder.cgi?class=team&type=b#gotresults&as=team_batting&offset=0&match=basic&suffix=&min_year_game=1913&max_year_game=2016&series=any&series_game=any&playoffs=&WL=any&game_length=nineinn&team_lg=&opp_id=&opp_lg=&use_dh=&HV=V&game_site=&temperature_min=0&temperature_max=120&wind_speed_min=0&wind_speed_max=90&wind_direction_tolf=1&wind_direction_tocf=1&wind_direction_torf=1&wind_direction_fromlf=1&wind_direction_fromcf=1&wind_direction_fromrf=1&wind_direction_ltor=1&wind_direction_rtol=1&wind_direction_unknown=1&precipitation_unknown=1&precipitation_none=1&precipitation_drizzle=1&precipitation_showers=1&precipitation_rain=1&precipitation_snow=1&sky_unknown=1&sky_sunny=1&sky_cloudy=1&sky_overcast=1&sky_night=1&sky_dome=1&number_matched=1&orderby=HR&c1criteria=PA&c1gtlt=eq&c1val=27&c2criteria=&c2gtlt=eq&c2val=0&c3criteria=&c3gtlt=eq&c3val=0&c4criteria=&c4gtlt=eq&c4val=0&c5criteria=&c5gtlt=eq&c5val=1.0&c6criteria=&firstteamgames=&startteamgames=&lastteamgames=&ajax=1&submitter=1) (**criteria: plate appearances = 27; innings = 9; on the road** - since road teams are guaranteed to bat for 9 innings in 9 inning games) suggests that road teams on this list had 27 plate appearances (thus, 27 batters) in a 9-inning game. Of the 11 games I can see without a subscription, there was a hit in 6 games (taking a perfect game or no-hitter out of consideration in those 6 games).

After sorting the [search](http://www.baseball-reference.com/play-index/game_finder.cgi?class=team&type=b#gotresults&as=team_batting&offset=0&match=basic&suffix=&min_year_game=1913&max_year_game=2016&series=any&series_game=any&playoffs=&WL=any&game_length=nineinn&team_lg=&opp_id=&opp_lg=&use_dh=&HV=V&game_site=&temperature_min=0&temperature_max=120&wind_speed_min=0&wind_speed_max=90&wind_direction_tolf=1&wind_direction_tocf=1&wind_direction_torf=1&wind_direction_fromlf=1&wind_direction_fromcf=1&wind_direction_fromrf=1&wind_direction_ltor=1&wind_direction_rtol=1&wind_direction_unknown=1&precipitation_unknown=1&precipitation_none=1&precipitation_drizzle=1&precipitation_showers=1&precipitation_rain=1&precipitation_snow=1&sky_unknown=1&sky_sunny=1&sky_cloudy=1&sky_overcast=1&sky_night=1&sky_dome=1&number_matched=1&orderby=H&c1criteria=PA&c1gtlt=eq&c1val=27&c2criteria=&c2gtlt=eq&c2val=0&c3criteria=&c3gtlt=eq&c3val=0&c4criteria=&c4gtlt=eq&c4val=0&c5criteria=&c5gtlt=eq&c5val=1.0&c6criteria=&firstteamgames=&startteamgames=&lastteamgames=&ajax=1&submitter=1&z=1&z=1) by hits, at least 20 games had at least 2 hits under the same criteria above, the most recent taking place in [2013](http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/PIT/PIT201304190.shtml).